# VLookup: Single Search Key, Multiple Ranges, Index returned depends on the range, so not consistent

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have multiple sheets of student data. One sheet (we'll call it **BUILDING SHEET**) is for data entry by a building staff member. This sheet contains the Search Key, which is a column that has student IDs. At the end of this data table, there is a column that I am trying to populate with a date that is being entered on another sheet of data. The second sheet (we'll call it **DISTRICT SHEET**) houses form responses containing some similar student data as the Building Sheet, including five columns that could potentially contain Student IDs.

What I'd like to do is create an Array Formula that includes a VLookup which will take the Student ID entered in the Building Sheet, search for it in the District Sheet, and when it matches, pull the Date in the last column of the table. The issue I am running into is I can't figure out how to search the other columns in the District Sheet to return the Date if the Student ID isn't found in the first column of the first VLookup.

I tried two different formula builds. One with ImportRange as a part of the Array Formula/VLookup, and one where I used ImportRange to bring the data from the District Sheet into a tab on the Building Sheet, then Array Formula/VLookup from there.

=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup($D$2:$D,importrange("doc-ID-string","Form Responses 1!R2:CJ"),71),iferror(vlookup($D$2:$D,importrange("doc-ID-string","Form Responses 1!AD2:CJ"),59),iferror(vlookup($D$2:$D,importrange("doc-ID-string","Form Responses 1!AO2:CJ"),48),iferror(vlookup($D$2:$D,importrange("doc-ID-string","Form Responses 1!AZ2:CJ"),37),iferror(vlookup($D$2:$D,importrange("doc-ID-string","Form Responses 1!BY2:CJ"),12),"")))))

This will populate a date, but they are populating sporadically and incorrectly. In the Building Sheet, four rows of student data contain unique Student IDs, but those IDs are spread across columns R, AD, AO, and AZ in a single row in the District Sheet. The date that should return for that row is 8/28/23. Two of the rows in the Building Sheet have the correct date populate, but one row is blank (no error) and one pulled another date from another row in the District Sheet.

=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup($D$2:$D,'District Data'!$R$2:$CJ,71),iferror(vlookup($D$2:$D,'District Data'!$AD$2:$CJ,59),iferror(vlookup($D$2:$D,'District Data'!$AO$2:$CJ,48),iferror(vlookup($D$2:$D,'District Data'!$AZ$2:$CJ,37),iferror(vlookup($D$2:$D,'District Data'!$BY$2:$CJ,12),"")))))

This results in the same as above, despite bringing the data from the District Sheet into a tab in the Building Sheet.

What I had expected was that as a building staff member entered the student data in a row in the Building Sheet, the Array Formula would grab the Student ID and search Column R in the District Sheet for a match. If there's a match, it would return the Date entered in Column CJ. If there's no match, it would then search Column AD for the Student ID. It would follow this pattern for Columns AO, AZ, and BY, but anywhere there is a match, it would return the Date in Column CJ.

Answer (score 0):

One way to follow the pattern of first looking into one column, then in the next one and so on is by nesting XLOOKUP. XLOOKUP has a fourth argument in case there's no match, inside it you can put a new XLOOKUP.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP(K2:K,C2:C,I2:I,
  XLOOKUP(K2:K,E2:E,I2:I,
   XLOOKUP(K2:K,G2:G,I2:I,))))
```

If you don't want to repeat the ranges you can use LET:

```
=LET(v,K2:K,r,I2:I,
 ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP(v,C2:C,r,
   XLOOKUP(v,E2:E,r,
    XLOOKUP(v,G2:G,r,)))))
```

Obviously, adapt it to your ranges.

[image]